# _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>

Tags: flutter

Someone can help me? I get errors when running the code.

This full code errors

```
Restarted application in 5,728ms.
D/EGL_emulation(12613): app_time_stats: avg=500967.44ms min=177.41ms max=1001757.50ms count=2
D/EGL_emulation(12613): app_time_stats: avg=1551.20ms min=1551.20ms max=1551.20ms count=1
E/flutter (12613): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _LoginScreenState#96e43(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (12613): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (12613): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (12613): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (12613): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (12613): #1      State.setState
E/flutter (12613): #2      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (12613): #3      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (12613): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (12613): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (12613): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12613):
```

This Login Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login/api_service.dart';
import 'package:login/otp_verify.dart';
import 'package:login/login_page.dart';
import 'package:snippet_coder_utils/FormHelper.dart';


class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  
  

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  TextEditingController patientNoController = TextEditingController();
  bool isAPICallProcess = false;

  String patientPhoneNumber = '+60176713856';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final patientNoController = TextEditingController();
     
    final logo = Hero(
      tag: 'logo',
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 40.0,
        child: Image.network(
          "https://i.imgur.com/bOCEVJg.png",
          height: 180,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          
        ),
      ),
    ); 
    final txtPatientNo = TextField(
      controller: patientNoController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Phone Number',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
        )
        ),
       
    );
    
    final btnLogin = RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Verify"),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      onPressed: (){
        if (patientNoController != null && patientNoController.text =="+60176713856");
          

              });
              APIService.signin(patientPhoneNumber).then((respone) async {
                setState(() {
                  isAPICallProcess = false;
                });
               if (respone) {
                 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                   context, 
                   MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (context) => OtpPage(
                       
                     ),
                   ), 
                   
                   (route) => false,
                   
                );
               }

      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Patient Login Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
          children: <Widget>[
          logo,
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          txtPatientNo,
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          btnLogin,
        ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is? I'm new to using flutter. I want to use TextEditingControl and create an APICallProcess. But my problem. I stack the first page. Is my coding correct or not. Someone can explain to me so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because after you call `setState` you immediately call `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`. `setState` will execute the passed callback (in this case `() {isAPICallProcess = false;}`, and marks to widget to be rebuilt.

But you `Navigator` call can execute pretty quickly, so there is a chance when  the engine tries to rebuild this login page of yours after `setState`, it is no longer in the widget tree, and is disposed.

I don't know what do you use this `isAPICallProcess` but my guess is that you do not really need it after this widget is disposed. So you can avoid this error message with this, checking for the widget's mounted state:

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    isAPICallProcess = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir error solve and I can run the code. But I don't know why when I enter the number. The number auto deletes before I push verify button.

Comment: That's because you are creating a new `TextEditingController` in every build method. Remove it from build method, create it as a class member, like after `String patientPhoneNumber`, so that it will be created only once. Also add a `dispose` method to you state class and call `patientNoController.dispose()` to dispose it properly.

Comment: It's work. But when I enter the phone number. It can't verify and go to the next page for getting otp number.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue than the original question. If you update the code and point out where is your problem I will have a look at it. Or you can post a new question.